# Strange CreateFile behaviour

Tags: c, winapi

Strange [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) behaviour. I am tiring to open file

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"E:\\temp\\1.txt",  
    GENERIC_READ,          
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,     
    NULL,                   
    OPEN_ALWAYS,             
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
    NULL); 

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Could not CreateFile\n");
    return;
}
```

File is opened no error (don't know is it target file).. for some reason in the directory where is my application running empty file "E"(wiout extention) created during CreateFile call. What is wrong here?

Comment: Is that the only call to `CreateFile()` in your application?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes.. i debuginng and see that reason of creating "E" is that CreateFile

Comment: Your use of `IS_ERROR` is wrong. It checks `HRESULT` values for error, in your case you have a `HANDLE` type and you must use `if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` to test for an error.

Comment: @FelixDombek i changed so also, but have no error. If i am using L"C:\\autorun.inf" instead of L"E:\\temp\\1.txt" the "C" file is created in app dir(corrected the post).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get rid of the `L` prefix of your filename string. You are calling the narrow version of `CreateFile` (`CreateFileA`) and passing in a wide string.

Alternatively, you can set VS to build your app using Unicode.

In either case, you should use the `_T()` macro to set the appropriate string type. i.e.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_T("E:\\temp\\1.txt"),
```

Comment: It wouldn't compile if the narrow version was being called. At least it wouldn't in C++, but C might do something insane and let it go.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast - I wouldn't think it would have compiled either, but the fact that it's creating a file whose name is just the first letter implies a narrow/wide mismatch.

Comment: [Found it!](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/VVs) GCC and Clang hate it, but wow, just wow.

Comment: @Ferruccio correct reason. Thanks!  but  _T() isn't visible by compiler in my C project (that is user mode app for fs filter driver wdk8.1 tool set)

Comment: Well, after not being able to update my comment for some time, here's the rest: I really hope this doesn't happen on higher warning levels because trying to use the Windows API appropriately by using the wide versions of functions would be terrible if this slipped in somewhere.

Comment: @Brans As an alternative to using the `_T()`-macro you could be explicit in your invocation of the API by calling either `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW`, and use the respective character string encoding without having to worry about a mismatch.